# Swing full size JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

How to reach a full width of outerPanel ?

```
    private JPanel createLabelPanel() {

        final JToolTip tt = new JToolTip();
        //tt.setSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        final CompoundBorder cb = new CompoundBorder(tt.getBorder(), BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2, 2, 2, 2));
        final JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel();
        innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        innerPanel.setBorder(cb);
        innerPanel.setBackground(tt.getBackground());
        innerPanel.add(displayLabel);
        innerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));

        final JScrollPane tooltipscrool = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
        //tooltipscrool.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200,100));
        tooltipscrool.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,120));
        tooltipscrool.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        final JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel();
        outerPanel.add(tooltipscrool);
        outerPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
        //outerPanel.set
        return outerPanel;
    }
```

makes me:

[image]

and my aim is to have a full width of innerPanel (the green one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout` by default, which tends to what to use the preferred size of each component to define their size.

Instead use a `BorderLayout`, for example...

```
final JPanel outerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
```

Take a look at [How to layout components within a container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

You should also avoid using `setPreferredSize` where possible, check out [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) for more details

Comment: I did not aware of that JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default, thanks ! I cannot click UP :/

Comment: No worries, you should be able to click the greenish click soon, if your satisfied with the answer ;)

Comment: @MrPhi Getting in's not the problem ;)